# Add unallocated space to free space

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, ssd

[image: discs order]

The `Free` space was a partition with Linux, so I just deleted the partition (didn't have a "Format" option) and it became "Free". Then I just shrank the `D://` drive with some 50 GB.

Now I want to add the `Unallocated` to the `Free` space, or vice-versa, I don't care, I just want to merge them into one bigger partition. Nevertheless, the options from the drop-down menu (upon a right-click on one of the space blocks) does not give me options for that. I could probably use some 3rd party software, but I kind of believe the built-in Windows tools can do stuff like and I would like to get to know some tips on that. Trying to "Delete" the `Free` space warns me that it *is an extended partition and deleting it will result in it become **inaccessible*** so I am not quite sure what can this lead to...

I am with `Samsung SSD 840 EVO` if that is of any importance to you.

Comment: Does it helps to make that Free space unlocated and than merge them ?
about deleting partition. http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/323109-cant-delete-partition.html

Comment: You have to do the partitions in order.  You have to allocate the 50.29GB before you can merge the 65.37GB space with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 65GB Free space is in an extended partition, that means the 50GB unallocated is not in any partition at all, so you should be able to expand the 65GB Free/Extended partition all the way to the left, overtaking the 50GB unallocated. That should work with `gparted` but I'm not too sure about windows.

But they are both empty space you want to re-use, so **deleting** the 65GB "free space" extended partition and **then** **creating a new (extended) partition** with all the then-unallocated space should accomplish the same thing, and may even be a better idea in case the program decides to try to move the "free" extended partition first, or if it can't grow an extended partition.

Comment: Indeed. Deleting and recreating the extended partition (aka “Free space” aka the green thingy) is perfectly safe because it’s empty.

Comment: Oh, nice! When I actually deleted the "Free space" it merged with the "Unallocated" automatically. I did not perform this before, because I was afraid of the *deleting it will result in it becoming **inaccessible***. Thanks, guys!